# Unwind in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am doing aggregation for creating invoice. So I have 3 collections invoice, pitchedProduct and products. In my invoice I have the pitchedProduct Id so by using it I am able to access PitchedProduct collection and in my pitchedProduct collection I have product Id so to access product Id I have to first unwind the pitchedProduct output to access its inner elements. But by doing so the invoice data which is projected is also shared in multiple objects.Is it possible that I can query without unwind so that duplicate date does not create.

here is my query

```
db.invoices.aggregate([

  { $lookup : { from: "productsPitched", localField:"pid", foreignField:
    "idx", as:"pitchedProduct"  }},

  { $unwind: "$pitchedProduct" },

  { $lookup : { from: "products", localField:"pitchedProduct.pid", foreignField: "idx", as:"products"  } },

  { $project:{idx: true, pid: true, pmt: true, amtc: true, isv: true, dt:true,

   products: {idx: true, nm: true },

   pitchedProduct: { idx: true, pid: true}}}
] )
```

And the output I am getting is

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58fde1e14afe1e3578b3ff86"), "pmt" : [ 30 ], "pid" : 

[ 87 ], "amtc" : 19550, "isv" : false, "dt" : 1493033441840, "idx" : 30, "products" : [ { "idx" : 2, "nm" : "garuda" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58fde2704afe1e3578b3ff89"), "pmt" : [ 31, 32 ], "pid" : [ 86, 75 ], "amtc" : 143750, "isv" : false, "dt" : 1493033584309, "idx" : 31, "products" : [ { "nm" : "Garuda Lite", "idx" : 1 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58fde2704afe1e3578b3ff89"), "pmt" : [ 31, 32 ], "pid" : [ 86, 75 ], "amtc" : 143750, "isv" : false, "dt" : 1493033584309, "idx" : 31, "products" : [ { "nm" : "Garuda Lite", "idx" : 1 } ] }
```

I want to access pitchedProduct data without unwinding it because as I unwind it the whole data is converted into multiple objects which is not a good solution.

How can I achieve this??

Feel free to ask any questions if you don't understand..

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways to resolving the problem but the below  solution is more applicable to your case.

You can use `$addFields` which will extract the product pitched `pid's` instead of `$unwind`. So this way you can directly pass the `pitchedproductpid` to the `$lookup` just similar to the way you did for `pid` in first `$lookup`.

Something like below

```
db.invoices.aggregate([
  { $lookup : { from: "productsPitched", localField:"pid", foreignField:"idx", as:"pitchedProduct"  }},
  { $addFields : {pitchedproductpid:"$pitchedProduct.pid"}},
  { $lookup : { from: "products", localField:"pitchedproductpid", foreignField: "idx", as:"products"  } },
  { $project:{idx: true, pid: true, pmt: true, amtc: true, isv: true, dt:true,products: {idx: true, nm: true },pitchedProduct: { idx: true, pid: true}}}
] )
```

Comment: This is great.. A learning for me . Thank you.. I haven't heard of this property before. Is there more like $addFields ? Please suggest me some links where I can learn more about these. :) Thanks..

Comment: You are welcome. Here is the landing page for all aggregation stages.https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/

Comment: Also can  I assign two values of project for eg pid and pmt to an object? like obj = [{pid:1},{pmt:2}]???

Comment: Something like `{$project:{obj: [{pid:"$pid"},{pmt:"$pmt"}]}}` ? I'm not sure what exactly you refer here. Can you give me little bit more information ?

Comment: In the output of aggregation I have an array of pmt and pid, I want to create an array in which the 1st object will be the 1st value of pid and pmt as in the output above the obj will somewhat look like this obj = [{pmt:31,pid:86},{pmt:32,pid:75}] .. ??

Comment: You can try something like `{"$project":{"obj":{"$map":{"input":{"$zip" :{"inputs" :["$pid","$pmd"]}},"as":"zip","in":{pid:{$arrayElemAt:["$$zip", 0]},pmd:{$arrayElemAt:["$$zip", 1]}}}}}}`. This is quite straightforward. It will zip the array values together into array of arrays, iterate and map them out as key value pair for each array element.

Comment: Its giving an error "Use of undefined variable: zi‌​ p"

Comment: Can you show me your query ? Is there a space between the zi & p ?

Comment: `db.invoices.aggregate([{ $lookup : { from: "productsPitched", localField:"pid", foreignField: "idx", as:"pitchedProduct" } },{ $unwind: "$pitchedProduct" },{ $lookup : { from: "products", localField:"pitchedProduct.pid", foreignField: "idx", as:"products" } },{ $addFields : {pitchedproductpid:"$pitchedProduct.pid"}},{"$project":{"obj":{"$map":{"input":{"$zip" :{"inputs" :["$pid","$pmd"]}},"as":"zip","in":{pid:{$arrayElemAt:["$$zi‌p", 0]},pmd:{$arrayElemAt:["$$zip", 1]}}}}}}])`
assert: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "Use of undefined variable: zi‌p",
 "code" : 17276,

Comment: No m sry there was no space between zi & p

Comment: There are some special character (???) possibly because of incorrect encoding. Please copy the query to text editor to view them and then to your code. I also noticed you are still using $unwind. Do we need that ?

Comment: Thanks brother I debug the mistake it was a silly one :P Thanks for your help.. Really appreciated :)